# Null value error when trying to make viewmodel item equal variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am creating an MVC application where I am sending an email to JIRA.  I initially had it working when I had the ModelType in the view just IssueTable, but when I changed it too ModelType ViewModelClass.ViewModel it stopped working correctly.

In the controller:

```
Public Function SubmitIssue(issuetable As IssueTable, test As IssueTracker.ClientUserProjectIssue ) As ActionResult

Dim mail As New MailMessage()
mail.Subject = issuetable.IssueSummary
Dim body As String = test.iTable.IssueDescription
mail.Body = body
smtp.Send(mail)
```

In the view:

```
@ModelType IssueTable

@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.IssueSummary)
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.IssueDescription)
```

This initially worked but I needed to have multiple tables to send data so I created a viewModel like this:

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Public proTableList As List(Of ProjectType)
    Public cTableList As List(Of ClientTable)
    Public proTable As ProjectType
    Public iTable As IssueTableViewModel
End Class

Public Class IssueTableViewModel
    Public IssueSummary As String
    Public IssueDescription As String
End Class
```

In the view I displayed information like this:

```
@ModelType IssueTracker.ViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.iTable.IssueSummary)
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.iTable.IssueDescription)
```

Now the problem lies in my in the controller because the way I am trying to populate the description and summary like this I get a null error:

```
Public Function SubmitIssue(issuetable As IssueTable, test As IssueTracker.ClientUserProjectIssue ) As ActionResult

Dim mail As New MailMessage()
mail.Subject = test.iTable.IssueSummary
Dim body As String = test.iTable.IssueDescription
mail.Body = body
smtp.Send(mail)
```

As you can see apart from the obvious ViewModel Class added to the code it is the exact same.

This is clearly must not be correct way to get a value into a variable / email by using a viewModel, does anyone know how I can do this correctly?

Comment: I don't see a mail.to and mail.from are these set elsewhere ?

Comment: Yes That is just a simple string to an email address and it is working so i left it out only having trouble with the body and subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `BindAttribute` from you controller method, or change it to be `<Bind(Include:="iTable")>`

Your view model does not contain properties named `IssueID`, `IssueSummary` and `IssueDescription`, only a property named `iTable` (which in turn contains those properties).

However your using a view model, and a view model should only contain the properties you need in the view, which means you should not need a `BindAttribute` on your method.

Assuming your editing only the `IssueSummary` and `IssueDescription` properties of `IssueTable` (as per your code), then your view model should be

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Public proTableList As List(Of ProjectType)
    Public cTableList As List(Of ClientTable)
    Public proTable As ProjectType
    // Public iTable As IssueTable // delete this
    Public IssueSummary As String // add this
    Public IssueDescription As String // add this
End Class
```

Comment: I still get the null error for: Dim body As String = test.iTable.IssueDescription in my application when I change to <Bind(Include:"iTable")> or take it out.

Comment: Not unless you have other errors in your code. I will create a DotNetFiddle to prove it a bit later (but the code will be in c#)

Comment: Sorry it prevents the null error but now the value being sent is just blank

Comment: As I noted in my answer, what you really should be doing is include the `IssueSummary` and `IssueDescription` in `ViewModel` (not have a separate mode for them and delete `Public iTable As IssueTableViewModel`. Then in the view its `@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.IssueSummary)` etc. but you POST method parameter needs to be `Public Function SubmitIssue(test As ViewModel)` - because thats what your view is rendering